# Unable to get user name from the People Picker control using jQuery

Tags: jquery, people-picker

I want to do some operation based on the user entered in the people picker control.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
$("input[title='Project Owner']").focusout(function () {

    //var User = $("textarea[title='People Picker']").val().split("\\");
     //user = $.trim($("#Project Owner").text());
    //var user = $().SPFindPeoplePicker({
    //    peoplePickerDisplayName: "Project Owner"

    //});
    alert("Hello");
    var user = $(this).val();

    alert(user);

});
});
```

The `foucusout()` event runs perfectly but I am not getting the user name. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

After searching too much I got some thing to get the display name of the user:

code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[title='Project Owner']").focusout(function () {




    var loginName = $("span.ms-entity-resolved").attr("title");

    alert("Login Name:" + loginName);

    var displayName = $("span.ms-entity-resolved div:first-child").attr("displaytext");

    alert("Display Name :" +displayName);

});

});
```

Hope this helps to other.

Answer (score 0):

The People Picker controls are tricky little things.

You might want to take a look at [this blog post](http://sympmarc.com/2012/04/22/working-with-sharepoint-people-pickers-with-jquery-a-new-function-called-findpeoplepicker/) by Marc Anderson which seems to cover the ground to wish to.

Comment: I went through that blog post could not get idea that's why I posted my question here.